# Хорошие книги и туторы по программированию avr

Tags: c, avr

Можете подсказать хорошие книги и туторы по программированию avr для новичков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 10 практических устройств на AVR-микроконтроллерах. Кравченко А.В.
2. Микроконтроллеры AVR: от простого к сложному. Голубцов М.С.
3. Самоучитель по микропроцессорной технике. Белов А.В.
4. Разработка устройств на микроконтроллерах AVR. Белов А.В.
5. Практическое программирование микроконтроллеров Atmel AVR на языке ассемблера. Ревич Ю.В.

Answer (score 0):

Евстифеев А. В. Микроконтроллеры AVR семейства Mega